# How process click button ios?

Tags: ios7

I have 3 `view.view 0 (0,0,320,300)`,`view 1 (0,300,320,300)`,`view 2 (0,300,320,300)`and 1   button.
`view 0` doesn't change position.When I don't click button `view 2` override `view 1` but when I click button,I set position of `view 2(0,600,320,300)`.I use auto layout on storyboard.

**CODE**

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _contraintAfter = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_view1
                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                  toItem:_view2
                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                               multiplier:1
                                               constant:0];
   _btnInfoView.selected = NO;
  }
  #pragma mark - Auto Layout



  -(void)layoutInfoAppeare
  {
       [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^{
                     [self.view removeConstraint:_contraintBefore];
                     [self.view addConstraint:_contraintAfter];
                     [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     _view1.hidden = NO;
                 }];
  }



-(void)layoutInfoDisappeare
{
 _view1.hidden = YES;

 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^{
                     [self.view removeConstraint:_contraintAfter];
                     [self.view addConstraint:_contraintBefore];
                     [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                 }];
}

and when i click button i process:

   - (IBAction)btnVaccineOtherClick:(id)sender
   {
     UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;

      btn.selected = !btn.selected;

     if (btn.selected) {
       [self layoutInfoAppeare];
    } else {`
      [self layoutInfoDisappeare];
   }
  }
```

I don't understand,When I click button the first `view 2` doesn't change position.But When I click the second `view 2` change position.Can you help me?

Comment: if you use auto-layout, you could not change the `frame`, `bound` or `center` properties directly.

Comment: i can set frame..but i add contraints it can change position...